# how to read from binary file into struct c?

Tags: c, file

i have the following struct

```
struct
{
    char order;
    int row;
    int column;
    int length;
    char printChar;
}record;
```

and my file look's like this

```
F
30
40
7
X
```

how can i use fread to store the file in the struct?
does my file appear correctly or should all the components need to be in one-line?

Comment: The file is ok, but if you have an element on each line then it is better to use `fgets`.

Comment: "and my file look's like this"... It doesn't look like a binary file. Is it, in fact, binary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking if you can do

```
struct record r;
fread(file, &r, sizeof(r));
```

or are you forced to use

```
struct record r;
fread(file, &r.order, sizeof(r.order));
```

If this is your question, then the answer is: you have to read the fields one-by-one since there may be padding between struct members. Or, if you use a GNU-compatible compiler, you might instruct it not to include any padding by declaring your struct as "packed":

```
struct record {
    // ...
} __attribute__((packed));
```

But this is not advised unless absolutely necessary (it's not portable).

Also, is your file really a binary file? If not, you should pay attention to newline characters and converting the numbers from text to their actual numeric value.

Comment: i intend to use a binary file , are there any ways to create a real binary file without fwrite?

Comment: @DanielHallel What do you mean by a "real" binary file? Why do you want to avoid using `fwrite()`?

Comment: from what i understand if i open an empty .bin file with notepad and add  30 it will be 2 char's one 3 and the other 0 , but isn't there a way to save 30 in a binary format? oh and i want to avoid using fwrite because my program handles already created binary files so i dont want to create one..

Comment: @DanielHallel Now go read its documentation, `fwrite()` doesn't (re)create the file if you tell it not to do so. By the way, if you're not concerned by endianness problems, just use `int i = 30; fwrite(&i, sizeof(i), 1, stream);`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to read from a file in that format (essentially containing the character representations of the data) into the structure.  One method for reading it would be to use [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) and read each line and assign the data into the structure (converting numeric values as necessary with functions such as [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or perhaps [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atol) if error checking is not as important).

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems to be a text file, so if that's exactly the format of the file, you can use `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(file, "%c%d%d%d%c", &(record.order), &(record.row), ...
```

You can check the return value if you're interested in basic error handling. If you need a better description of the error, just use `fgets` to read one line at a time and parse it with `sscanf`, `atoi`, `strtol` and similar functions.

If you want to directly save data in the structure, no, you can't (with that kind of file), in a text file `30` is a string of two characters, not an integer in binary form.